# Call segue after AFNetworking success crash app

Tags: ios, afnetworking, segue

I'm trying to create a login screen for my ios app, I've managed to get the json back after authentication but when I try to call a segue to move from the login screen to the dashboard after authentication it's not working.

What I pretend to do is a basic login, user put his API Key on the input, clicks submit and if it's ok it goes to the dashboardViewController.

check my code:

```
- (IBAction)touchLogin:(id)sender {    

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.site.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , id JSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"Got JSON: %@", JSON);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSuccesful" sender:self];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON){
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong. %@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], JSON);
    }];

    [operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
    {
        if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0)
        {

            NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.apiKeyTextField.text
                                                                password:@""
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

            [[challenge sender] useCredential:creds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *errorString = @"Incorrect API Key";
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [errorAlertView show];

            NSLog(@"Previous auth challenge failed. Are username and password correct?");
        }
    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

I've created the segue and put the identifier "LoginSuccesful", I'm not sure if I should call the segue inside that code block.

When I run the app I get the NSLog with the JSON, but the app crash when tries to do the segue and show me the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'LoginSuccesful'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

But if you look at my storyboard file, I've created this segue and even put the navigation controller.

[image]

Does anyone had this problem already? Can someone let me know how can I call another ViewController after the authentication is ok?

I'm not sure if this is the best approach even for the error alert view as well, but it's working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the first view controller (as in the screenshot). Then, on the menu, go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. After you do this the second nav controller is unnecessary. You can drag the segue between View Controller and Table View Controller. As you can see from the error the problem is that the "source controller" doesn't have "an instance of UINavigationController".

Comment: is there a way to do not display the navigation bar on my login screen? I was trying to do something like facebook login, just the logo and fields

Comment: for this you should select the first navigation controller in storyboard and set "Top Bar" to "None".

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the root view of your NavigationalController is not the main ViewController.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the error, do you know how I can do it without having the nav bar on my login screen?

Comment: navController.setNavigationBarHidden = YES;